# Setting minimum in EAActionSheetPicker

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to set minimum date to be today (in my app you can work only in present and future) and it's simple to manage it in regular UIDatePicker by `setMinimumDate:` but I'm using EAActionSheetPicker for ease and there is no Minimum or Maximum date properties.

Is it me or you cannot acomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Minimum or Maximum date in  **EAActionSheetPicker.m** file

```
-(UIDatePicker *)datePicker{
    if(!_datePicker){
        _datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:PICKER_FRAME];
        _datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    }
    return _datePicker;
}
```

in this method you can set the minimum or maximum date simply using

```
_datePicker.minimumDate=[NSDate date];
```

Comment: Oh god, what a shame I didn't think of that... Thank you very much for your help!